# Is it safe to heat fluorite (CaF2) to 140 °C?

Tags: heat, temperature, toxicity

For the manufacture of the optical system, we need to heat the fluorite ($\ce{CaF2}$) lenses to $\pu{140 °C}$. Is it possible:

1. for some poisonous gas to be emitted? ($\ce{F2, HF}$ or other)
2. for defects to appear on the glass? (scratches, chips, cracks and the like)

If yes, please supply sources describing the corresponding scenarios.

Comment: The melting point is over 1400C. There's no way it can evolve F2 without electrolysis. Think you'll be safe at 140C

Comment: @Waylander Thanks, but I have  concerns like operator live saliva (1 mg) which ph <7. Then there will be reaction which  released HF.

Comment: Unless your operators drool is highly acidic (pH1 or lower) then they are not going to produce HF.

Comment: @Waylander thanks, if you want give me answer below, and I'm ready to accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The melting point of $\ce{CaF2}$ is over $\pu{1400°C}$. There is no way $\ce{F2}$ can be generated without electrolysis of the molten $\ce{CaF2}$. $\ce{HF}$ is produced by reaction of conc sulfuric acid on $\ce{CaF2}$. Concentrated $\ce{HCl}$ does react with fluorite to some extend, but the reaction is very slow so, unless your operators drool like the monster from *Alien*, there is no chance of $\ce{HF}$ formation.

Comment: Some operators, though...

Comment: I guess you could link an MSFS showing how safe $\ce{CaF2}$ is …

Comment: The MSDS for fluorite is here: http://www.sciencelab.com/msds.php?msdsId=9927120  The major concerns are contact with eyes and skin.